# Why does this d3 chart render with crosses, then get rid of them upon moving a node?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization, sankey-diagram

I've built a d3 sankey diagram adapted from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/Neilos/584b9a5d44d5fe00f779) to show the flow of prerequisites for courses in my program. However, instead of letting the library auto-position the nodes, I've manually set their `x` and `y` coordinates to minimize crosses with this short bit of code before calling `update();`

```
if (!AUTO_POSITION) {
    exampleNodes.forEach((r, i) => {
        r.x = r.xPos;
        r.y = r.yPos;
    });
}
```

The chart originally renders like this (note the line crosses near MATH 100, MATH 101, PHYS 101, PHYS 102, ELEC 211, ELEC 311, etc.):

[image]

However, when you click and drag any one node, the diagram adjusts to this (note most crosses disappear):

[image]

Why does the program do this? And how can I get the diagram to render without the crosses upon loading?

I've tried hackily firing the events of a node being clicked and dragged upon loading, but there is a bit of a delay and needs the mouse to be moved to work. Also, I'd only use this as a last-measure workaround.

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initEvent("mouseup", true, true);
evt.initEvent("mousedown", true, true);
document.querySelector("g.node").dispatchEvent(evt);
```

The full code for my example is in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/2qz018w0/). Thanks.

Comment: The code is about 1500 lines! Could you create a minimal code representing your problem without unnecessary details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to make a timeout function like this:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    //does the relayout
    biHiSankey.relayout();
    //update all the nodes with new height
    svg.selectAll(".node").selectAll("rect").attr("height", 
     function (d) { 
        return d.height; 
    });
    //update all the path
    link.attr("d", path);
  }, TRANSITION_DURATION +450);
```

Inside the `update` function.

This will get triggered after the transition is complete.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/q0dgm2tr/)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work for updating the links, however the node size doesn't update to match the new links. Do you know how to update those as well?

Comment: done! please check my answer..i have updated the nodes with its new height. Also updated the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! Still not sure why it's doing this to begin with, but that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right it's because the order of the data in your array does not match the order of their position. The array-order seems to determine in which order the dependencies are shown, unless you reposition any of the elements, which results in a rerendering.

I've tried reordering some elements of the data array, to follow the positions on the chart, and their size and the dependency-links between them automatically rendered fine.

I also noticed, that some elements, though listed in the array, do not get displayed in the chart, as they do not have any dependencies added.